# convert a number or string to binary number in python?

Tags: python-3.x, string, binary, numbers

sample input:
B15
sample output:
B15 in binary = 1011000010101

I've tried

```
a = input()
print(bin(a))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The hexadecimal number 0xB15 = 2837 has the binary representation 0b101100010101. So if your input is a hexadecimal number, you need to tell Python to convert the string `"B15"` which comes out of `input()` into the hexadecimal number `0xB15`, also known as the decimal number `2837`, before you can convert it into binary for output.

```
BASE = 16
a = int(input(), BASE)
print(bin(a)[2:]) # Cut of the first two characters '0b'
```